# Ansible DistributionNotFound jinja2

Tags: ansible

When I run the following ansible command

```
ansible webservers -m ping
```

It reports "DistributionNotFound jinja2<2.9". I then updated jinja to 2.9.4 :

```
pip install --upgrade jinja2
```

But ansible still reports the same error when running it. Does anybody can help? Thanks!

Comment: How did you install ansible? Via pip, apt/yum, source?

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov Via pip, release is 2.2.1.0

Comment: DistributionNotFound issue is generally caused by multiple ansible installations via different sources... check system packages presence.

Comment: What are the results of `which pip`, `which python`, `which ansible` and `ansible localhost -m raw -a "which python"` (if the latter runs at all)? You did upgrade on the control machine, not the target node, right?

Comment: @techraf Yes, I upgraded on the control machine. My pip, python and ansible are all installed and run from /usr/local/python27/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually figured out the solution, which is to update distribute rather than jinja2. Then reinstall ansible (my ansible was initially installed via pip):

```
pip install -U distribute
pip uninstall ansible
pip install ansible
```

Thanks to @KonstantinSuvorov and @techraf for your help.